# MySQL Find closest date and corresponding records between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to get the closest subscription date to each order date (only for subscription dates that are before order dates) and also the corresponding cancellation date. Is there anyway to do this? I use mainly MySQL but any SQL variant that works in Snowflake should be ok.

My Code:

```
Select DISTINCT o.ORDER_ID, o.CUSTOMER_EMAIL, o.order_DATE min(subs.START_DATE)

FROM ORDERS o
INNER JOIN subscriptions subs

GROUP BY ORDER_ID, CUSTOMER_EMAIL
,ORDER_DATE
ON o.CUSTOMER_EMAIL = subscriptions.CUSTOMER_EMAIL
```

ORDERS Table:

| ORDER_ID | ORDER_DATE | CUSTOMER_EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 20/02/2021 | jay@gmail.com |

Subscriptions table:

```
|SUBSCRIPTION_ID | START_DATE | CUSTOMER_EMAIL | CANCEL_DATE |
|----------------|------------|----------------|-------------|
|1236            | 20/03/2021 |jay@gmail.com   |   20/04/2021|
|1232            | 19/02/2021 |jay@gmail.com   |   19/03/2021|
|1219            | 20/01/2021 |jay@gmail.com   |   29/01/2021|
```

Expected Result:

| ORDER_ID | ORDER_DATE | CUSTOMER_EMAIL | EARLIEST_SUBSCRIPTION_START | CLOSEST_SUBSCRIPTION_START | CLOSEST_SUBSCRIPTION_END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 20/02/2021 | jay@gmail.com | 20/01/2021 | 19/02/2021 | 19/03/2021 |

Answer (score 1):

A snowflake focused solution:

So with some CTEs for to fake the data:

```
WITH orders(order_id, order_date, email) AS (
    SELECT column1, to_date(column2,'DD/MM/YYYY'), column3 FROM VALUES
    (1234, '20/02/2021', 'jay@gmail.com')
), subscriptions(subscription_id, start_date, email, cancel_date) AS (
    SELECT column1, to_date(column2,'DD/MM/YYYY'), column3, to_date(column4,'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM VALUES
    (1236, '20/03/2021', 'jay@gmail.com', '20/04/2021'),
    (1232, '19/02/2021', 'jay@gmail.com', '19/03/2021'),
    (1219, '20/01/2021', 'jay@gmail.com', '29/01/2021')
)
```

and this SQL:

```
SELECT
    o.order_id,
    o.order_date,
    o.email,
    FIRST_VALUE(s.start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY o.order_id, o.order_date, o.email ORDER BY s.start_date) as EARLIEST_SUBSCRIPTION_START,
    start_date AS CLOSEST_SUBSCRIPTION_START,
    cancel_date AS CLOSEST_SUBSCRIPTION_END
FROM orders AS o
JOIN subscriptions AS s
    ON o.email = s.email AND o.order_date > s.start_date
QUALIFY row_number() over(PARTITION BY o.order_id, o.order_date, o.email ORDER BY s.start_date desc ) = 1
```

we get:

| ORDER_ID | ORDER_DATE | EMAIL | EARLIEST_SUBSCRIPTION_START | CLOSEST_SUBSCRIPTION_START | CLOSEST_SUBSCRIPTION_END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-02-20 | jay@gmail.com | 2021-01-20 | 2021-02-19 | 2021-03-19 |

This is using the WINDOW function [FIRST_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/first_value.html) to get the first row for each row, then we use [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) to drop the rows (per order,oder_date,email) that are not the first when sorted by subscription date in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, editing my answer.  It isn't really clear what you are asking in total.  If you just do a simple INNER JOIN LIKE:

```
SELECT ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE, orders.CUSTOMER_EMAIL, subscriptions.START_DATE, subscriptions.SUBSCRIPTION_ID, subscriptions.CANCEL_DATE, DATEDIFF(ORDER_DATE, subscriptions.START_DATE) as DIFF

FROM orders INNER JOIN subscriptions ON orders.CUSTOMER_EMAIL = subscriptions.CUSTOMER_EMAIL

WHERE ORDER_DATE < subscriptions.START_DATE
```

You get results that look like:

```
ORDER_ID    ORDER_DATE  CUSTOMER_EMAIL  START_DATE  SUBSCRIPTION_ID CANCEL_DATE DIFF
1234        2021-01-20  jay@gmail.com   2021-02-20  1232            2021-03-19  -31
1234        2021-01-20  jay@gmail.com   2021-03-20  1236            2021-02-20  -59
```

Seems like you would have to place an order before the subscription starts, the the other way around ?  Not sure what you mean by earliest vs. closest either.

Adding an update, which seems closer and requires the customer e-mail as the parameter:

```
SELECT ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE, orders.CUSTOMER_EMAIL, earliest.EARLIEST_SUBSCRIPTION_START, closest.CLOSEST_SUBSCRIPTION_START, closestcancel.CLOSEST_SUBSCRIPTION_END  from orders
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT MIN(START_DATE) as EARLIEST_SUBSCRIPTION_START from subscriptions WHERE CUSTOMER_EMAIL = 'jay@gmail.com') earliest ON orders.CUSTOMER_EMAIL = 'jay@gmail.com'
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DATEDIFF(subscriptions.START_DATE,orders.ORDER_DATE) as days, START_DATE as CLOSEST_SUBSCRIPTION_START from orders INNER JOIN subscriptions ON orders.CUSTOMER_EMAIL = subscriptions.CUSTOMER_EMAIL WHERE orders.CUSTOMER_EMAIL = 'jay@gmail.com' ORDER BY ABS(days) LIMIT 1) closest ON orders.CUSTOMER_EMAIL = 'jay@gmail.com'
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DATEDIFF(subscriptions.CANCEL_DATE,orders.ORDER_DATE) as days, CANCEL_DATE as CLOSEST_SUBSCRIPTION_END from orders INNER JOIN subscriptions ON orders.CUSTOMER_EMAIL = subscriptions.CUSTOMER_EMAIL WHERE orders.CUSTOMER_EMAIL = 'jay@gmail.com' ORDER BY ABS(days) LIMIT 1) closestcancel ON orders.CUSTOMER_EMAIL = 'jay@gmail.com'
```

You would have to run it on your own table since I'm not sure the data is correct.  It is looking forwards and backwards in time for the "Closest" (sorting by Absolute value), so you might have to adjust some things there.

Comment: Thanks Sscotti, have tried this out but doesn't seem to get the th desired result.

Comment: Hey Sscoti sorry I've updated my tables to hopefully make things clearer. Basically subscriptions (service) could be made before and/or after an order (item) is made.

Comment: So for each order, I would only want 1 row with each of the various subscription information in each column